# Missing config in my k3s configmap used by my gitlab-runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, k3s

I'm trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot application onto my k3s cluster (namespace 'kubernetes-demo' using a gitlab runner (which is via helm installed in the aforementioned namespace).
I keep the error that I have missing fields, but I have no idea how to fill them.

From my master node:

```
root@master1:~# kubectl describe configmap gitlab-runner -n kubernetes-demo
Name:         gitlab-runner
Namespace:    kubernetes-demo
Labels:       app=gitlab-runner
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              chart=gitlab-runner-0.54.0
              heritage=Helm
              release=gitlab-runner
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: gitlab-runner
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kubernetes-demo

Data
====
check-live:
----
#!/bin/bash
if /usr/bin/pgrep -f .*register-the-runner; then
  exit 0
elif /usr/bin/pgrep gitlab.*runner; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi

config.template.toml:
----
[[runners]]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    namespace = "kubernetes-demo"
    image = "docker:19.03.12"
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
  [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
    name = "docker-socket"
    path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
    mountPath = "/var/run/docker.sock"
  [[runners.kubernetes.volume_mounts]]
    name = "docker-socket"
    mountPath = "/var/run/docker.sock"

config.toml:
----
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 30
log_level = "info"

entrypoint:
----
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mkdir -p /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/

cp /configmaps/config.toml /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/

# Set up environment variables for cache
if [[ -f /secrets/accesskey && -f /secrets/secretkey ]]; then
  export CACHE_S3_ACCESS_KEY=$(cat /secrets/accesskey)
  export CACHE_S3_SECRET_KEY=$(cat /secrets/secretkey)
fi

if [[ -f /secrets/gcs-applicaton-credentials-file ]]; then
  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/secrets/gcs-applicaton-credentials-file"
elif [[ -f /secrets/gcs-application-credentials-file ]]; then
  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/secrets/gcs-application-credentials-file"
else
  if [[ -f /secrets/gcs-access-id && -f /secrets/gcs-private-key ]]; then
    export CACHE_GCS_ACCESS_ID=$(cat /secrets/gcs-access-id)
    # echo -e used to make private key multiline (in google json auth key private key is oneline with \n)
    export CACHE_GCS_PRIVATE_KEY=$(echo -e $(cat /secrets/gcs-private-key))
  fi
fi

if [[ -f /secrets/azure-account-name && -f /secrets/azure-account-key ]]; then
  export CACHE_AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME=$(cat /secrets/azure-account-name)
  export CACHE_AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY=$(cat /secrets/azure-account-key)
fi

if [[ -f /secrets/runner-registration-token ]]; then
  export REGISTRATION_TOKEN=$(cat /secrets/runner-registration-token)
fi

if [[ -f /secrets/runner-token ]]; then
  export CI_SERVER_TOKEN=$(cat /secrets/runner-token)
fi

# Register the runner
if ! sh /configmaps/register-the-runner; then
  exit 1
fi

# Run pre-entrypoint-script
if ! bash /configmaps/pre-entrypoint-script; then
  exit 1
fi

# Start the runner
exec /entrypoint run --user=gitlab-runner \
  --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner

pre-entrypoint-script:
----

register-the-runner:
----
#!/bin/bash
MAX_REGISTER_ATTEMPTS=30

# Reset/unset the not needed flags when an authentication token
RUN_UNTAGGED=""
ACCESS_LEVEL=""

if [ ! -z "$REGISTRATION_TOKEN" ] && [ "${REGISTRATION_TOKEN#glrt-}" != "$REGISTRATION_TOKEN" ]; then
  RUN_UNTAGGED=""
  ACCESS_LEVEL=""
  unset REGISTER_LOCKED
  unset RUNNER_TAG_LIST
fi

for i in $(seq 1 "${MAX_REGISTER_ATTEMPTS}"); do
  echo "Registration attempt ${i} of ${MAX_REGISTER_ATTEMPTS}"
  /entrypoint register \
    ${RUN_UNTAGGED} \
    ${ACCESS_LEVEL} \
    --template-config /configmaps/config.template.toml \
    --non-interactive

  retval=$?

  if [ ${retval} = 0 ]; then
    break
  elif [ ${i} = ${MAX_REGISTER_ATTEMPTS} ]; then
    exit 1
  fi

  sleep 5
done

exit 0


BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
root@master1:~#
```

Gitlab console log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0 (b72e108d)
  on gitlab-runner-XXXXX XXXXX, system ID: XXXXX

Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: kubernetes-demo
Using Kubernetes executor with image docker:19.03.12 ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...

Preparing environment
00:00
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up build pod: Pod "runner-XXXXX-project-XXXXX-concurrent-XXXXX" is invalid: [spec.volumes[0].hostPath.path: Required value, spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "docker-socket", spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Required value, spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "docker-socket", spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Required value, spec.containers[2].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "docker-socket", spec.containers[2].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Required value, spec.initContainers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "docker-socket", spec.initContainers[0].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Required value]. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```